# I have two dataframe in pandas. I need to take input from second, get result from first and then print in second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame in pandas. First one(df1) has three columns: Objects, Location, Price.
In my second dataframe(df2), I have some objects listed down, and I need to find prices of them by looking up from the first data frame.
I need a generic code for the same, which means even if number of rows in both dataframe changes, there shouldn't be any effect on code.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Objects': {0: 'book', 1: 'copy', 2: 'pencil', 3: 'pen'},
 ' Location': {0: ' ground floor',
  1: ' first floor',
  2: ' ground floor',
  3: ' second floor'},
 ' price': {0: 60, 1: 40, 2: 5, 3: 10}})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Serial': {1: '1', 2: '2'},
 'Items': {1: 'copy', 2: 'pen'},
 'Price': {1: 'nan', 2: 'nan'}})
```

I need to find prices of items listed in df2 from df1 and write in price keeping the order intact in df2.

Output expected:

```
result=pd.DataFrame({'Objects': {1: 'copy', 2: 'pen'},
 
 ' price': {1: 40, 2: 10}})
print(result)


    Objects     price
1   copy        40
2   pen         10
```

I tried using for loops, but couldn't figure out when number of rows are unknown in df2

Comment: please include your data ,expected output and code as text that you tried in your question

Comment: updated @AnuragDabas

Comment: Just use `isin()` method and make use of boolean masking:`result=df1[df1['Objects'].isin(df2['Serial'])]`

Comment: The order of df2 would get messed up. Need to keep it intact.

Answer (score 0):

If the object names are the same across the two dataframes, you can just do df1[df1['object'] == 'nameofobject'][price].

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge Function of pandas if both data frame has one column in common. For example, if in second data frame there is one column as object it will solve your problem.
pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner', on='object')
Rename your df2 item to object and then use merge function